# App with deployment target of 7.0 won't run on device with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I understand the difference between base SDK and deployment target. What I don't understand is why when my app has a deployment target set to 7.0 (base is set to 8.4) it won't run on a device with 7.1 installed - XCode saying to connect to a device with a recent enough version of iOS. But it already is recent enough.

Comment: Did you check your Project settings AND your Target settings ?

Comment: That was it, thanks.